# cert-manager: Failed to register ACME account: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

Tags: cert-manager

I installed the cert-manager using the Helm Chart. I created a `ClusterIssuer` but I see that it's on a failed state:

```
kubectl describe clusterissuer letsencrypt-staging
ErrRegisterACMEAccount Failed to register ACME account: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

What could be causing this `invalid character '<'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is most likely the result of an incorrect server url, the url you specified is returning HTML (hence the complain about `<`).

Make sure that your server url is `https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"` and NOT just <strike>`https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/"`</strike>, the  **`/directory`** must be included in the url.

So the `ClusterIssuer` should look like this (emphasis on the **.spec.acme.server**)

```
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    email: name.surname@mycompany.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        route53:
          hostedZoneID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          region: eu-north-1
      selector:
        dnsZones:
        - xxx.yyy.mycompany.com
```